# Exclude div from 60% width within a wrapper

Tags: html, css, percentage, responsiveness

I'm creating a website that has the following setup:

```
<html>    
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper_devider">    
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div class="slider"></div> 
            <div id="container"></div> 
            <div class="sidebar"></div>  
            <div id="footer"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
```

The css is as following:

```
.wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1500px;
}

.wrapper_devider{
width:60%;
padding:0 20%;
}

#header{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

.slider{
display:block;
float:left;
width:100%;
background-color:#0000FF;
height:150px;   
}

#container{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #eeeeee;
display: inline;
}

#footer{
display:block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

The `.wrapper` has a fixed width of 1500px and the rest is done with %.
The thing I can't seem to fix is that I want the slider to be full width.
I have tried to set the width if the `.slider` to 1500px but it only expands to the right.

Can anybody see what I do wrong?

M.

Comment: Try adding `clear: both;` to your .slider class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper has a max-width of 1500, this is different then a fixed width, this would look like

```
width: 1500px;
```

Even if you set the width to 1500, it still won't work because your slider element is inside your divider.

I would recommend the following layout:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper_divider">    
            <div id="header">header</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">slider</div> 
        <div class="wrapper_divider">
            <div class="container">container</div> 
            <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>  
            <div class="footer">footer</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1500px;
}

.wrapper_divider{
  width:60%;
  padding:0 20%;
}

#header{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#0000FF;
  height:150px;   
}

#container{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: inline;
}

#footer{
  display:block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've made an example of how it would look: http://jsfiddle.net/zon1d0gz/

Comment: I will but it is to soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

**OPTIONS**

1. Move Slider outside of `.wrapepr`.
2. Make `.wrapper` 100% width and add new internal div of 60%.
3. If you cannot move the slider then make it `position:absolute` and offset the `.wrapper` with padding.

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1500px;
  padding-top:150px;
}
.wrapper_devider {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0 20%;
}
#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.slider {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 150px;
}
#container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: inline;
}
#footer {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper_devider">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. However I'm not that big of a fan to use `position:absolute;`

Comment: Yes this is not the way I would recommend however I thought you had no control over page layout and only had access to css.

Comment: No I have everything, but why did you think that (to prevent it in the future!)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.wrapper` class has `max-width:1500px`. This is an upper limit, I think you want: `width:1500px`.

```
.wrapper{
    width: 1500px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also `wrapper_devider` is set to 60%, so the slider won't span the entire 1500px since the slider is nested within `wrapper_devider`. I would remove that div entirely, you don't need it.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div class="slider"></div> 
        <div id="container"></div> 
        <div class="sidebar"></div>  
        <div id="footer"></div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the solution with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zf4opfz/)